# Reporting failures from anonyous PL/SQL blocks

Tags: plsql, custom-errors

The following SQL*Plus script

```
WHENEVER OSERROR EXIT FAILURE
WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT FAILURE

DECLARE
    EXIST_INDEXES BOOLEAN := FALSE;
BEGIN
    FOR INDEX IN (SELECT * FROM INDEXES)
    LOOP
        EXIST_INDEXES := TRUE;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(INDEX.SCHEMA || '.' || INDEX.NAME);
    END LOOP;

    IF EXIST_INDEXES THEN
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000,'Before proceeding, it is recommended to drop the indexes listed above');
    END IF;
END;

-- Here go SQL statements that should be executed if no indexes were found
```

produces this output when there is an entry in table/view INDEXES:

```
SCHEMA_1.INDEX_1
DECLARE
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-20000: Before proceeding, it is recommended to drop the indexes listed above
ORA-06512: at line 13
```

When there are entries in table/view INDEXES, how to:

- suppress the `DECLARE` and `*` lines from appearing in the script output;
- skip executing the SQL statements after the PL/SQL block;
- have the script return a non-zero code?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can customize the error output of SQL*Plus. The `DECLARE` however would be standard and you could filter this with a script afterwards.

Concerning your other question, the behaviour of SQL*Plus in case of error is governed by the [`WHENEVER SQLERROR`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve052.htm#i2700066) command. In your case if you want to exit with an error code in case of error you would enter the following command at the beginning of the script:

```
WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT FAILURE ROLLBACK
```